# Design pattern Doctrine ORM - Generate unique names based on input

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am working with Symfony2 and Doctrine ORM and want to achieve the following with a clean architecture :

Each time a new Entity is created, I want to save a "display name" chosen by my end-user, then generate a "unique name" based on the "display name".

If my end-user want to create 3 Project called "Drawings",

- the first one will have display_name = "drawings"
- the second one will have display_name = "drawings2"
- the third one will have display_name = "drawings3"

(or something like that, whatever the pattern)

Basic Entity example :

```
/**
 * Project.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name_display ;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name_unique ;

    //...
```

Basic usage example :

```
$project = new Project();
$project->setDisplayName('Drawings'); 
//Around here I would like the Unique name to be generated
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($project);
```

I thought about various solutions :

- Doing the name generation in the Controller, but it's not re-usable
- Doing the unique name generation in the repository. But it seem to be a bad practive (repositories should be read-only)
- Using a PrePersist LifecycleCallbacks from doctrine, but it's not a good practice as I need the Entity Manager to do a Database
- Doing the name generation in the Entity Setter, injecting the Entity Manager to make requests and look for available names. That looks horrible
- Using a service to persist the Entity as explained here : [Are Doctrine2 repositories a good place to save my entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369956/are-doctrine2-repositories-a-good-place-to-save-my-entities) (But it's quite complicated and involve a huge change in my infrastructure if I want to have all my Entity creations to be consistent with this practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the last options - services. It may need changes in your project, but I find this the best way to manage usual crud operations with entities - create, save, findBySomething ...

- It is crystal clear - no black magic. As opposed to events where there is no obvious relation between the executed code and actions with entities (like creating it through new).
- It is not dependent on annotations and it is easy to maintain.
- Controllers and other services may access this service through Dependency Injection which is a clear way of satisfying dependencies of business objects(objects holding business logic)
- Your repositories won't become bigger and bigger
- You can use default repositories - fewer issues with back compatibility when upgrading Doctrine
- It is much better than the "setter solution", which sounds really horrible - entities should never be that mighty, so they would have references to services (especially services like `EntityManager`)